# linux D state processes reboot still remain? how can i close it?

Tags: linux, centos

I have a 2cpu 4G server. Recently I found that the load is relatively high. I found a D states process after troubleshooting. I checked some information and said that only restarting can solve the problem.

But I restarted several times and the process is still there.

May I ask everyone, what is this process? process? How can this problem be solved?

Linux 5.10.60-9.al8.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Sep 6 21:30:37 CST 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
[root@test ~]# cat /proc/137/status 
Name:   load_calc
Umask:  0000
State:  D (disk sleep)
Tgid:   137
Ngid:   0
Pid:    137
PPid:   2
TracerPid:  0
Uid:    0   0   0   0
Gid:    0   0   0   0
FDSize: 64
Groups:  
NStgid: 137
NSpid:  137
NSpgid: 0
NSsid:  0
Threads:    1
SigQ:   1/14009
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
ShdPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000000000000
SigIgn: ffffffffffffffff
SigCgt: 0000000000000000
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: 000001ffffffffff
CapEff: 000001ffffffffff
CapBnd: 000001ffffffffff
CapAmb: 0000000000000000
NoNewPrivs: 0
Seccomp:    0
Seccomp_filters:    0
Speculation_Store_Bypass:   vulnerable
Cpus_allowed:   3
Cpus_allowed_list:  0-1
Mems_allowed:   00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000001
Mems_allowed_list:  0
voluntary_ctxt_switches:    59154
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches: 0

[root@test ~]# cat /proc/137/stack 
[<0>] load_calc_func+0x55/0x1a0
[<0>] kthread+0x11b/0x140
[<0>] ret_from_fork+0x22/0x30

[root@test ~]# ps -ef |grep load
root         137       2  0 15:34 ?        00:00:00 [load_calc]
root       11317    1645  0 19:01 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto load

top - 19:03:10 up  3:28,  1 user,  load average: 1.00, 1.00, 1.00
Tasks: 143 total,   1 running, 141 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu(s):  3.2 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 96.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   3538.5 total,    200.4 free,    774.7 used,   2563.3 buff/cache
MiB Swap:      0.0 total,      0.0 free,      0.0 used.   2461.8 avail Mem
```

Comment: Can someone help to check it out

Comment: Hello, the back-end verification has caused errors in the system load statistical logic due to the design flaws in the statistical features of Alibaba Cloud's self-developed rich container, resulting in the user's average load (load averages) result being always greater than 1 when the system is unloaded.
You can turn off the self-developed feature to make the load statistics display normal. Turning off this feature has no effect on system functions.
echo 0> /proc/async_load_calc

Answer (score 0):

That process's parent is `kthreadd`, pid=2. This is a kernel thread, not a “true” process. It appears as a process because it's scheduled like a process, but it runs kernel code, it doesn't have its own memory space.

I can't find any references to a kernel thread called `load_calc` or a kernel function running `load_calc_func` in the official Linux kernel. Check the kernel logs (`dmesg`) for clues.

Google turns up almost no hits for `load_calc_func`, which is fishy. It may be a legitimate thing from the Chinese OpenAnolis clone of RHEL; someone who knows Chinese (I don't) may be able to tell. It may be malware, in which case you can't trust anything you find in logs, you can't trust that the files you see on the disk are what's actually loaded in memory, and [you would need to reinstall your system from known good sources](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24195/how-do-you-explain-the-necessity-of-nuke-it-from-orbit-to-management-and-users).

Comment: Hello, the back-end verification has caused errors in the system load statistical logic due to the design flaws in the statistical features of Alibaba Cloud's self-developed rich container
You can turn off the self-developed feature to make the load statistics display normal. Turning off this feature has no effect on system functions.
echo 0> /proc/async_load_calc